# How to add accessibility for UIRefreshControl in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol, uiaccessibility, xcode9.2

I am trying to add accessibility for UIRefreshControl which has been implemented for pull to refresh in UITableView as below

```
self.refreshControl.accessibilityLabel = "Refreshing"
```

But if accessibility turned on and by swiping three finger on UITableview then does not speaking as Refreshing.

I override accessibilityScroll method as below.

```
override func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool {
    if direction == .up {
        self.refreshControl.accessibilityLabel = "Refreshing"
    }
    return true
}
```

Any idea Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any information on how a user performs a pull-to-refresh gesture with VoiceOver enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, refreshing is more than just scrolling up. Its scrolling up past y position 0. Otherwise this will happen whenever the user scrolls up. Secondly, use UIAccessibilityPostNotification to announce to the user that a UI element has just changed.

Comment: UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.announcement, argument: self.refreshControl?.attributedTitle?.string)